# C# how to remove circular dependency

Tags: c#

In our application, we have a Dataservice project which performs all the 'handshaking' with the DB via EF. We often use Scaffold-Dbcontext to update our models that sit within the Dataservice. I am now trying to introduce Hangfire, but because this generates a bunch of tables I've set this so that Hangfire sits in it's own DB.

I have an AuditLog table that is within the main project and needs to be updated by hangfire.

So, within the Hangfire project I made a reference to my dataservice so that I could reference the AuditLog object to be able to write to it. But now I need to reference the Hangfire project from the Dataservice to run the methods on it and so now have a circular dependency error:

So in my hangfire project I have:

```
public  class HangFireService : DbContext, IHangFireService
{
    private DbContext _context;
    private readonly IBackgroundJobClient _jobClient;

    public HangFireService(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _jobClient = new BackgroundJobClient();
    }

    public void JobLogUpdate<T>(T origin, T newValues, string user) where T : class
    {
        _jobClient.Enqueue(() => LogUpdates(origin,newValues,user));
    }
......
 private void LogUpdates<T>(T origin, T newValues, string user) where T : class
 {
     AuditLog audit = new AuditLog() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ChangedBy = user, ChangedDate = DateTime.Now };
     Type myType = typeof(T);
     
     //first make sure same type
     if (origin.GetType() != newValues.GetType())
     {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Objects of different Type");
     }
     audit.Original = JsonSerializer.Serialize(origin);
     audit.NewValue = JsonSerializer.Serialize(newValues);
     audit.ObjectName = myType.Name;

     _context.Add(audit);
     _context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

and then in my data service I have:

```
var hangfire = new HangFireService(_context);
// where bookingOrig and BookingNew are both booking class
 hangfire.JobLogUpdate(bookingOrig, bookingNew, booking.CreatedBy);
```

How can I pass in class AuditLog so that I can remove the reference to the DataService in my Hangfire Project?

Comment: So decouple them. It's hard to say exactly where to do that but circular dependencies usually indicate a suboptimal architecture / project setup. It sounds like your data access layer is responsible for more than just reading from and writing to the database. Also, you can create a separate `HangfireDbContext` which connects to the separate Hangfire database, without creating an entirely different project. It's entirely valid to have multiple `DbContexts` in one project.

Comment: @nbokmans I had the hangfire class originally in the DataAccess layer because it's so small and then I didn't have an issue with circular ref's, but some bright spark, wants me to decouple the hangfire bit in-case they want to use it in other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If AuditLog class is a simple PoCo, you could create another project (class library) and put the class AuditLog. Your others projects could reference it and share AuditLog without circular dependencies.

Generally speaking, you should use the inversion of control pattern IMHO. With correct use of interface and concrete implementation, and a library for dependency injection, circular dependencies does not exists in my own personnal experience.

A third approach, could be to use a factory to create the AuditLog in HangFireService. This is valid if you have a top project wich has reference to the two others.
The constructor :

```cs
public HangFireService(DbContext context, Func<Guid,string,DateTime,object> createAuditLog)
{
    _context = context;
    _jobClient = new BackgroundJobClient();
    _createAuditLog = createAuditLog;
}
```

The first line of the method LogUpdates:

```cs
object audit = _createAuditLog(Guid.NewGuid(), user, DateTime.Now);
```

Then intanciate your HangFireService like that :

```cs
var hangfire = new HangFireService(_context, (id,changedBy,changedDate) => new AuditLog { Id = id, ChangedBy = changedBy, ChangedData = changedDate });
```

Comment: I agree, however this is an existing project and Hangfire is late to the party.  I would have designed the whole solution differrently if it had been my call, but unfortunatly it is what it is. your 3rd solution solves my issue for now, until re-design is possible. Thank you for the help.